# Why I cannot run a Qt Qml application on monitor with resolution 800x600?

Tags: linux, qt, opengl, qml, xcb

When I set the resolution to 800x600, my application crashes with the following errors:

```
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 460, resource id: 0, major code: 1 (CreateWindow), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 461, resource id: 37748745, major code: 2 (ChangeWindowAttributes), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 462, resource id: 37748745, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 463, resource id: 37748745, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 464, resource id: 37748745, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
etc.
```

But when I run a Qml application on a monitor with a resolution of 1920x1080 (or any other larger or equal to 1024x768) resolution, the application works fine.

- System: Archlinux 4.7.4-1-ARCH x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Qt: QMake version 3.0 Using Qt version 5.7.0
- libxcb: libxcb 1.12-1

It's seems like it is a Qt bug or  an xcb library bug.

UPD: I created [a bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56140) in bugreports.qt.io.

**This effect reproduced only for Qt Quick Controls 2 Application**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect not reproduced if delete next line of code( in main.cpp ):

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

Comment: @kuanyui , bug in Qt, you can see details in that [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56140).